# Microsoft SQL Server error certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate" when using bcp utility

Tags: sql-server, bcp, bulk-load

On Linux server I would like to bulk load data into a database table. I tried this command:

```
bcp dbo.ProjectStaging_AdIMI out test.txt -c -T -S localhost
```

but I get an error:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -1
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider:
> [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]
>
> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -1
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection.
> For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722

This is test computer and I don't need any encryption. I know for `sqlcmd` tool I need to use `-No` switch to disable this encryption, but I don't know which switch to use using `bcp` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the [-u BCP argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-bcp?view=sql-server-ver16#available-options) to trust the certificate with BCP version 18 and later:

```
bcp dbo.ProjectStaging_AdIMI out test.txt -c -T -S localhost -u
```

Comment: Using your command solved the "certificate" problem, then I have got: "SSPI Provider: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible. No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KCM:)" error. So I replaced -T with -U user -P password. Then I got error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.ProjectStaging_AdIMI'" so I added -d database. Final command is: `bcp dbo.ProjectStaging_AdIMI out test.txt -c -U user -P password -S localhost -u -d db01`

Comment: @folow, an alternative to specifying the database name with `-d` is to use a 3-part object name: `db01.dbo.ProjectStaging_AdIMI`